# jQuery get the <select> value rather than the selected <option> value

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the above example the console logs a value of 1 which is the currently selected option. How can you log the `<select>` tag's value of 2?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('.mySelect').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mySelect" value="2">
  <option value="1" selected>Choice 1</option>
  <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
  <option value="3">Choice 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use `$('.mySelect').attr("value")`

Comment: `select` doesn't have a `value` property, at least it's not a valid html property.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not valid HTML syntax.

Use data attributes like `data-someattr` for values you want to pass.

Comment: I can't understand cause of +7 vote to simple answer!

Answer (score -1):

This would work for you .

```
console.log( $('.mySelect[value=2]').val() );
```

Comment: You should use comment to clarification

Comment: Thank you. So i changed title as answer.